How to configure ipv6 with NO prefix delegation
Question Description
How to configure ipv6 with NO prefix delegation?
I'm trying to set up dual-stack (IPv4/IPv6) access for my br-lan interface on a Debian (arm64) system with kernel version 5.15. My upstream connection is through a wwan0 modem, and I want to provide dual-stack access to downstream clients connected to br0 (br-lan).
I've configured NetworkManager, ndppd, radvd, and wide-dhcp6, and set up the necessary configuration files and scripts. The clients connected to br-lan can ping addresses within the br-lan network and receive DHCPv6 addresses and DNS information. However, they cannot connect to the internet.
Any assistance and troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.
Software Stack

Kernel: 5.15
OS: Debian (arm64)
Network Management Tools: NetworkManager, ndppd, radvd, wide-dhcp6

Goal
Provide dual-stack access to br-lan.
Network Configuration
Upstream

Device: wwan0

Connection: modem

Dual-stack access: No prefix delegation

Configuration:
wwan0: flags=81<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.84.235.248  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 100.84.235.248
        inet6 240e:473:620:140c:10f8:8d5a:c303:7640  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



Downstream

Device: br0

Connection: br-lan

NetworkManager Settings: ipv4 shared, ipv6 ignore

Configuration:
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 240e:473:620:140c:2333::1  prefixlen 80  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::2045:34ff:fe79:4865  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 22:45:34:79:48:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4097  bytes 423481 (413.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2184  bytes 239531 (233.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



Configuration Files
/etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

/etc/ndppd.conf
proxy wwan0 {
    router yes
    timeout 500
    ttl 30000
    rule 240e:473:620:140c:2333::/80 {
        iface br0
        static
    }
}

/etc/radvd.conf
interface br0 {
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        AdvManagedFlag on;
        MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
        MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
        prefix 240e:473:620:140c:2333::/64 {
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr off;
        };
}

/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6s.conf
option domain-name-servers 2a09::;
option domain-name-servers 2a11::;
interface br0 {
        address-pool pool1 3600;
};
pool pool1 {
        range 240e:473:620:140c:2333::2000 to 240e:473:620:140c:2333::3000 ;
}

IPv6 Route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
240e:473:620:140c:2333::/80 dev br0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
240e:473:620:140c::/64 dev wwan0 proto kernel metric 700 pref medium
240e:473:620:140c::/64 dev br0 metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth9aa835b proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via 240e:473:620:140c:54cb:5bf7:3c38:2da5 dev wwan0 proto static metric 700 pref medium

Configuration Script: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ipv6-conf.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

interface=$1
event=$2
if [ "$interface" == "wwan0" ]; then
        prefix=$(ip -6 addr show dev wwan0| sed -e's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$//;t;d'|head -n 1|cut -f'1-4' -d':')
        # just assume prefix length /64 here
        echo "get prefix $prefix::/64"|systemd-cat -t ipv6_conf
        cp /etc/ndppd.conf.bak /etc/ndppd.conf
        sed -i "s/REPLACE_PREFIX_HERE/$prefix:2333::\/80/g" /etc/ndppd.conf
        cp /etc/radvd.conf.bak /etc/radvd.conf
        sed -i "s/REPLACE_PREFIX_HERE/$prefix:2333::\/64/g" /etc/radvd.conf
        cp /etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6s.conf.bak /etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6s.conf
        sed -i "s/PREFIX_MIN/$prefix:2333::2000/g" /etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6s.conf
        sed -i "s/PREFIX_MAX/$prefix:2333::3000/g" /etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6s.conf
        systemctl restart radvd
        systemctl restart ndppd
        systemctl stop wide-dhcpv6-server
        systemctl start wide-dhcpv6-server
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/proxy_ndp
        sleep 30
        echo "setting route" |systemd-cat -t ipv6_conf
        ip -6 addr add $prefix:2333::1/80 dev br0
        #ip -6 route add $prefix::/80 dev br0
        ip -6 route add $prefix:2333::/64 dev br0
        ip -6 route |systemd-cat -t ipv6_conf
fi

Problem
Clients connected to br-lan can ping all addresses on br-lan and receive DHCP6 broadcast addresses and DNS, but they cannot connect to the internet.
Example of a Windows Client

IPv4 Address: 10.42.0.86
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 DHCP Server: 10.42.0.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 10.42.0.1
IPv4 WINS Server: 10.42.0.1
IPv6 Addresses:

240e:473:620:140c:1413:a3cb:57ec:f26
240e:473:620:140c:2333::2000


Temporary IPv6 Address: 240e:473:620:140c:3177:43e1:6ebc:550f
Link-local IPv6 Address: fe80:1413:a3cb:57ec:f26%10
IPv6 Default Gateway: fe80::2045:34ff:fe79:4865%10
IPv6 DNS Servers:

2a09::
2a11::


Ping Test Results:

ping -6 fe80::2045:34ff:fe79:4865 or 240e:473:620:140c:2333::1: Success
nslookup AAAA microsoft.com or ping -6 2603:1030:20e:3::23c: Failure



It seems to me like my ipv6 routes have some issue, I tried adjusting following part of the dispatch script but no luck.
        echo "setting route" |systemd-cat -t ipv6_conf
        ip -6 addr add $prefix:2333::1/80 dev br0
        #ip -6 route add $prefix::/80 dev br0
        ip -6 route add $prefix:2333::/64 dev br0
        ip -6 route |systemd-cat -t ipv6_conf


Trying to reduce the subnet from /64 to /80, or indeed anything lower that /64 is probably not going to work as pretty much all systems are going to assume /64. You should ask your ISP for a subnet greater that /64 & allocate individual /64 subnets as required. My ISP issues /56 to each customer.

Also: Forget about using DHCPv6 on LAN side. Google had already stated they wont support it for Android and insist on you have to configure SLAAC instead.

Prefix lengths other than /64 break SLACC (among other IPv6 feature that get broken).

Your ISP is using 240e:473:620:140c::/64 on the WAN side of your Debian router. You are then trying to use the same prefix, 240e:473:620:140c::/64, on the LAN side of this router. This is not a workable configuration.
You need to use a different prefix on the LAN side. As it stands, your ISP has effectively given you a single /128, so the only workable configuration is to use IPv6 ULAs on the LAN (use a /48 or /64 from fd00::/8 on the LAN), and use many-to-one NAT66 on the router so that all internet-bound packets have source IPv6 address 240e:473:620:140c:10f8:8d5a:c303:7640 (that of your router's WAN interface), This is identical to the way in which NAT(44) is commonly used in IPv4 networks, with the ULA range taking the role of RFC1918 address space.
What you should do in this situation is tell your ISP to get their act together and delegate you a prefix like they're supposed to.
